# What is the next diagram, and what is the number?

Tags: mathematics, cipher, visual, sequence

I needed some help to a friend of mine, he was solving a puzzle. He sent me a remake of what he was solving, and its up to you to help my friend!

---

[image]

[image]

Note:
My friend says that he messed up at 32, there is supposed to be 1 dot in postions 6 and 9.

Comment: Is the 32 diagram definitely correct? The border around it makes it look like there should be a 6/7/8/9th digit. The obvious pattern would make it the 9th digit, but I doubt thats what you're looking for

Comment: @IsaacRoan Sison Shouldn't it be just 1 dot in position 9 and no dot in position 6? in 32, i mean

Answer (score 2):

I believe the number in the middle (position 1) should be 128, this doubles each iteration. This number should be enclosed by a square. Outside this square, there should be two squares/dots on each edge (in positions 2, 3, 4 and 5). One final square should enclose the entire system, and there should be no squares/dots in positions 6, 7, 8, 9.